# Magento 2 - Export/Import Product Attributes

Tags: magento2, attributes, product-attribute

I'm trying to export my Product Attributes from one store to a new clean store database. I created a mysqldump for the following tables:

```
catalog_eav_attribute
eav_attribute_group
eav_attribute_label
eav_attribute_option
eav_attribute_option_swatch
eav_attribute_option_value
eav_attribute_set
eav_entity
eav_entity_attribute
eav_entity_datetime
eav_entity_decimal
eav_entity_int
eav_entity_store
eav_entity_text
eav_entity_type
eav_entity_varchar
eav_form_element
eav_form_fieldset
eav_form_fieldset_label
eav_form_type
eav_form_type_entity
```

The attribute is shown in the product attributes overview, but when I'm trying to access the products overview in the admin area I get a message 'Attribute with attributeCode "merk" does not exist.'.

I've imported a view products that uses these attributes and they imported fine, nu error message that the attribute could not be found.

Did I miss a table?

Comment: did you run `php bin/magento indexer:reindex` ??