# Magento 2: Import/Export Product Attribute Set & it's Attributes

Tags: magento2, attributes, product-attribute, importexport, attribute-set

I refer [Magento 2 - Export/Import Product Attributes](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/104399/magento-2-export-import-product-attributes) but no one answered :(

I have already created new Attribute Set & it's Attributes. I have checked Magento Default Import/Export for Products. It will do with all products.

I just want to export My newly created Attribute Set & it's Attributes. I have added in my Local. Now want to upload on a server. **Can't override DB/Table.**

Can manage through CSV or Custom Code?

Comment: you can replace database from local to live, if your local repo are same as server. first backup live db and try with above

Comment: @Rakesh Is you see from question i `Can't orverride DB/Table`.

Comment: Why Down Vote? Provide Reason please

Comment: @Rakesh If need to do using database then what will be query from which tables?

Comment: you have to just replace entire database from old to new one into sever, Also i am not believe in downvote.

Comment: you can just same process as done in local, import csv into live and check it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46452/discussion-between-rakesh-and-ankit-shah).

Comment: hi @AnkitShah can you guide me for import custom product attribute in m2

Answer (score 0):

You could try inserting the data manually by exporting the data from your local database, and running a SQL command like this for each of the tables you need to import with the data from your local table.

INSERT INTO `catalog_eav_attribute` (`attribute_id`, `frontend_input_renderer`, `is_global`, `is_visible`, `is_searchable`, `is_filterable`, `is_comparable`, `is_visible_on_front`, `is_html_allowed_on_front`, `is_used_for_price_rules`, `is_filterable_in_search`, `used_in_product_listing`, `used_for_sort_by`, `apply_to`, `is_visible_in_advanced_search`, `position`, `is_wysiwyg_enabled`, `is_used_for_promo_rules`, `is_required_in_admin_store`, `is_used_in_grid`, `is_visible_in_grid`, `is_filterable_in_grid`, `search_weight`, `additional_data`) VALUES

There are obviously more than just one table that will require your attention, but this is the fastest solution that I found.

Comment: HI @Collin Blake can you give me more hint on this as I know along with catalog_eav_attribute table you need eav_attribute table for import product attribute.I am trying to create a module for this but on validation i got error.Thanks ..

Answer (score 0):

Default magento does not provide this feature.

if you have large store and you wants to import / export all attributes and update then you can simply use the any plugin for this feature.

You can use some extensions to use this feature in community version:

https://marketplace.magento.com/mageaurigait-importexport.html
https://marketplace.magento.com/code007-attribute-import-export.html
https://marketplace.magento.com/commerceextensions-module-productattributes-import-export.html

Comment: every time I bump into this I still cannot believe it is not an option in default export. The FIRST choice you have to make when creating a product is product type and attribute set they should be the main options you can filter an export by.